# Why does setting an objects key as its value within a loop make the value undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious as to **why when you set a certain object's key as its own value in a loop, it returns undefined.**

For example:

```
var string = 'this is is it', someObj = {}, words = string.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    someObj[words[i]] = someObj[words[i]]; //Pay attention here
    console.log(someObj);
}
someObj;
```

Outputs:

[image]

Ofcourse, with a little type coercion you can do some fun stuff:

```
someObj[words[i]] = (someObj[words[i]] || 0)+1;
```

Outputs:

[image]

But why does it return undefined in the first place?
**I'd like to understand the concept behind this.**

Comment: You really haven't thought about this very hard. Why would you expect it to be defined in the first place if that value has never been encountered before?

Comment: Ask yourself: "what is the value of `someObj[words[i]];` before I do the assignment?" The correct answer is "it is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically before any assignment, `someObj[words[i]]` returns `undefined`.

Then you assign `undefined` and this is the result.

```js
var string = 'this is is it',
    someObj = {},
    words = string.split(' '),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(someObj[words[i]]);
    someObj[words[i]] = someObj[words[i]]; //Pay attention here
    console.log(someObj);
}
```

The mentioned solution checks the acutal value for truthiness and if falsy it returns a value.

```
someObj[words[i]] || 0  // returns either a truthy value from the left side or zero
// undefined      || 0 --> 0  right value
// 0              || 0 --> 0  right value
// 1              || 0 --> 1  left value
```

```js
var string = 'this is is it',
    someObj = {},
    words = string.split(' '),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(someObj[words[i]] || 0);
    someObj[words[i]] = (someObj[words[i]] || 0) + 1;
    console.log(someObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
someObj[words[i]] = someObj[words[i]];
```

the code implies, in `someObj` find a key with value of `words[i]` and assign it the value of `someObj[words[i]]`, Which happens to be `undefined` for each value of `i`.

Comment: `someObj[words[i]]`  is not undefined? @charlietfl. If an object's property which doesn't exist is accessed, the result is `undefined`. Please help me understand what you mean by inaccurate.

Comment: Please leave a good reason for the downvote, or undo it. Deleting comments after a downvote is not constructive criticism.